# Verify email on appwrite (my docker container) without mobile

Tags: appwrite

var result = await account.createVerification (url:'http://192.168.20.49:81/v1/account/verfication' );
sends a link to the mail
(http://192.168.20.49:81/v1/account/verfication?userId=63972f2f56d0c39fc9f8&secret=5025d...a&expire=2022-12-20+12%3A08%3A11.784)
Redirects to the browser and in the browser window json

```
{"$id":"6396bde6604188965bab","$createdAt":"2022-12-12T05:36:38.796+00:00","$updatedAt":"2022-12-12T15:44:11.741+00:00","name":"Andrey","registration":"2022-12-12T05:36:38.795+00:00","status":true,"passwordUpdate":"2022-12-12T15:44:11.741+00:00","email":"andrey253@yandex.ru","phone":"","emailVerification":true,"phoneVerification":false,"prefs":{}}
```

how to make sure that mail on the site is verified without redirection to the mobile? Can I create a page on the site for verification? And why verification does not happen automatically when clicking on the link, it would be very convenient!

For me a problem to receive in the userId and secret application in flutter from url http://192.168.20.49:81/v1/account/verfication? userId=63972f2f56d0c39fc9f8&secret=3ab63c4dee.41&expire=2022-12-20+19%3A42%3A10.896.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `http://192.168.20.49:81/v1/account/verfication`, you'll need to pass a URL to some page or something that will receive the secret so you can make the update verification API call. You can either host a web page to do it or set up a universal link that will link the user into your app where you can handle it in your app.